# Unity Instantiate and set position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want deactivate a `GameObject` and have particles explode as it disappears. I Instantiate and set the position of the particles but the particles look out of position as they fire. They do go to the correct position fine.

The issue I think is that the position is 0,0 when they are Instantiated and firing and then they get moved.

I have not been able to find a way to set the position as they Instantiate.

```
for (int i = 0; i < part.drawingPoints.Length; i++)
    GameObject particles = (GameObject)Instantiate(particlesPrepab);//instaiate object
    particles.transform.position = points.GetChild(part.drawingPoints[i]).transform.position;
    points.GetChild(part.drawingPoints[i]).gameObject.SetActive(false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public GameObject particles;

Instantiate(particles, transform.position , Quaternion.identity);
```

I'm not an expert, just tossing this really.

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
GameObject particles = (GameObject)Instantiate(particlesPrepab, points.GetChild(part.drawingPoints[i]).transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
```